# How do I create hyperlinks with a formula or rollup?

Tags: airtable

I have a table of items, each has a Name and a URL.

How can I combine the two and create a field that stores the hyperlinked Name, linking to its respective URL?

Furthermore, would it be possible to do the same with not just a formula field, but a rollup field?